# Boot freezing on "Failed to start Samba NMB Daemon"

Tags: boot, bluetooth

I turned my computer on to find that it can't complete the boot process fully, telling me that it's failing to start the Samba NMB Daemon. It appears to be linked in with a particular Bluetooth driver, but I'm unaware of any reasons that this would prevent it from booting. My system is running Ubuntu 22.10, and I can still access GRUB. Here are some photos showing the different errors I'm getting:

[image]

[image]

After running fsck from USB:

[image]

I have a live installation disk (running 22.04), but I am unsure how to approach checking driver integrity on my partition from here, if this is indeed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I get that exact same Bluetooth and Samba error.
Then I control-alt-Delete and the system restarts back to a clean Linux + Lenovo splash screen to an Ubuntu login screen, from where I get a clean login.
My configuration is complex through.

Windows 11 22h2 dual boot with Ubuntu 22.  This initially worked fine and clean.  But my Ubuntu partition was too small now that I was using it for my main day to day "daily driver".
So I shrunk the Windows partition, then made a new ext4 partition in the newly freed space.
Then I did a dd from the first ubuntu partition into my new larger ubuntu partition.
then the fireworks began.
Ended up with two partitions with the same uuid.

To get to be able to boot at all, I booted into recovery, then run dpkg to update and fix errors.
Then update Grub.
Then reboot.
That should get your through to a login screen.

After you get to login,
from a terminal, run:
sudo apt install arch-install-scripts
Then run a script called genfstab, I made entries to put into /etc/fstab to mount the new larger partition by partitionlabel instead of uuid.
Thus
sudo genfstab -t PARTLABEL /
then copy & paste the useful parts of the output into /etc/fstab

You will need to look at the output and use only the entries that are mounting your new larger Ubuntu partition.  Good idea to also include the comments that say what the entry is doing.
Then reboot.
Then see that same Fail Samba message, ctrl-alt-Del, and  rejoice when you see that login screen.

That overcame the duplicate uuid problem.
So give that a try, then ctrl-alt-Del when you get that hang, wait it out as the computer reboots back to to the login screen again, and log in.
This is not a complete fix yet.
Repeat that this isn't a complete fix yet, because I still haven't solved how to get a clean boot without first doing that ctrl-alt-Del at a Samba error hang first.
This does, however get you going and able to work on solving the problem fully.
Please do post if you find a way to solve this all the way through, and I will too if I do.